# Erlang determine "type" of remote node

Tags: erlang, nodes, cluster-computing

I have multiple nodes, of 2 types.

One type of node, will do one work on a specific server, the other one will do something else.

Let's call them "type1" and "type2".

I'm launching them with :

```
erl -pa ebin -name type1@sub1.mydomain.com -setcookie abc
erl -pa ebin -name type2@sub2.mydomain.com -setcookie abc
erl -pa ebin -name type1@sub3.mydomain.com -setcookie abc
```

sub1.mydomain.com, sub2.mydomain.com and sub3.mydomain.com are 3 different servers over internet.

Clearly, type2 node is here to interconnect both type1 together. Type2 server is the only "sure" node that is alive for the whole thing to work.

Type1 servers are dynamic, so everytime I run a new type1 server, it will ping type2 server in order to connect to all other nodes.

Thing is, when at least 2 type1 node are up and running, I need to cluster the work.

So I would like to determine from the nodes() return, which node are type1...

I would be able to get the string from atom_to_string, and then check the type1 with the returned string, but it seems like a wrong way to do it... Also using specific ports is not possible due to limitations.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Erlang, node names are *atoms* and atoms are *constant literals*, so you won't be able to pattern match on parts of an atom (in Greek, "a-tomos" means "unsplittable").

Unfortunately, you'll have to do something like converting each atom to a string (a list of chars) and then apply your regexp to it (it seems you're already doing so).

Said that, I would suggest you to have a look to:

http://learnyousomeerlang.com/distributed-otp-applications

OTP will help you with many of the things you're trying to achieve with your distributed application.